# HTML and Google Maps

Tags: html, css, dictionary

Simple question here. I'm learning Web dev and I would like to create a border with  a title and beneath it I want to put a google map view. Here is what I have in my css file "mystyle.css":

```
html{
height: 100%;   
}

div.map{
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
}

div.title{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 5px solid blue;
margin: 0px; 
text-align: center;
}

#map-canvas { 
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
}
```

Then on my index.html this is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Google Maps Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?MY_MAP_KEY&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="title"><h1>Google Maps Test</h1></div>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
```

My problem is that all I can see is the blue border with the text "Google Maps Test" I can't see the map view. Strangely enough, if I rename **div.title** to **body**, then I can see the map. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing your closing </div> tag on #map-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
#map-canvas {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
```

instead of

```
#map-canvas { 
height: 50%;
width: 50%;
}
```

And use `<div id="map-canvas"></div>`

instead of

`<div id="map-canvas"/>`